# Delphi firemonkey MAC OSX error sound when using various keys in memos

Tags: macos, delphi, firemonkey

Whenever I use the arrow keys inside a TMemo and some other controls, on the MAC it plays the error sound (like there is nothing in an edit control and you press backspace).

I am certain this is a delphi bug.

Is there any solution  beside telling my customer to set the volume to 0 to stop this behavior? It does this when using arrow keys, backspace, del and many other keys. It does this only on MAC OSX, not on Windows target.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I have a similar problem.

Comment: No, never got any info or fix for it as of now :(

Comment: Did you file a bug report in Quality Portal?

Comment: What version of Delphi do you use? - I tried both TMemo and TEdit in Delphi 10.2 Tokyo and did not get any error sounds. However, I still have the problem with all other controls.